# I'm getting error saying import error: 'ethers'.'provider' is not exported from 'ethers' (imported as 'ethers')

Tags: ethers.js

- ethers version that i am using:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "ethers": "5.2.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
...
```

I'm facing error at provider

```
import { ethers }  from "ethers";

...
...

    const provider = new ethers.provider.Web3Provider(
      socialLogin.provider,
    )
```

Entire Error line is:

```
export 'ethers'.'provider' (imported as 'ethers') was not found in 'ethers' 
(possible exports: BaseContract, BigNumber, Contract, ContractFactory, FixedNumber, 
Signer, VoidSigner, Wallet, Wordlist, constants, errors, getDefaultProvider, logger, 
providers, utils, version, wordlists)
```

Answer (score 0):

"ethers": "5.2.0", It's providers not provider.

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
      socialLogin.provider,
    )
```